# Sample random rows

Tags: r, random, subset, sampling

I have a data set in which there are multiple ID's, which have two observations/values each, e.g:

```
 ID           Test   Behaviour     
 A12.4.2      ONE     8.64      
 A12.4.2      TWO     7.63      
 A6.3.3       ONE     1.81      
 A6.3.3       TWO     2.47      
 B12.4.1      ONE     1.17      
 B12.4.1      TWO     3.96      
 E9.4.2       ONE     13.04     
 E9.4.2       TWO     9.51
```

I have found that to randomly sample rows to retain data on both ID's and the observation data associated with those ID's that I can use:

`df[sample(nrow(df), 32), ]`

However, I am struggling to find a function that will ensure that the two measures for each ID are included within the random sample. In the end, I would like a random sample made up of 16 ID's with two observations each, totaling 32 observations. Can anyone help?

Comment: Thank you for your comments - I've added a section of the input data to my question. Ideally I would like the output to be in the same format, just as a subset. I hope that this helps.

Comment: I take it you have more than the 16 row pairs you want to sample, right?

Comment: Correct, I'm just not allowed to give away the whole data set!

Answer (score 2):

You can sample 16 `unique` *ID*'s with `sample(unique(df$ID), 16)`. Those can be used to subset *df* using `%in%`. As you have two observations/values per *ID* this will give you 32 rows holding both observations of an *ID*.

```
df[df$ID %in% sample(unique(df$ID), 16),]
#   x ID
#1  1  A
#2  2  A
#5  1  C
#6  2  C
#7  1  D
#8  2  D
#11 1  F
#12 2  F
#15 1  H
#16 2  H
#19 1  J
#20 2  J
#21 1  K
#22 2  K
#23 1  L
#24 2  L
#31 1  P
#32 2  P
#33 1  Q
#34 2  Q
#39 1  T
#40 2  T
#43 1  V
#44 2  V
#45 1  W
#46 2  W
#47 1  X
#48 2  X
#49 1  Y
#50 2  Y
#51 1  Z
#52 2  Z
```

Data:

```
df <- expand.grid(x=1:2, ID=LETTERS)
```